# How to subset a dataframe based on a list of value in r

Tags: r

I have a big dataframe and a list of value (character). I want to subset the dataframe based on one column which contains value in the list. What should I do?

Thanks
Leilei

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide a Minimal reproducible example. See here: <https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want something like this..
Please make a reproducable example next time ://

```
data.frame(letters = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), value = 1:4) -> df
list("a", "y", "b", "x") -> subset_list

df[df$letters %in% subset_list,] -> df_subset
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want. Will make an example next time. Thanks!